# Django test with generated sql

Tags: django, unit-testing, testing

How can i use generated `.sql` file to use in tests?

So django should create test db then just import sql file without doing migrations.

Is that possible?

Comment: Do you want to get the Database creation script that django used to create the database?

Comment: I want to import this sql file in db, and avoid to django create tables and do all migrations on test db.